# in postgres, splitting an update between two tables using Rules

Tags: sql, postgresql, rules

attempting to maintain an edit log using rules.

```
create table t1(
    id serial primary key,
    c1 text,
    ... );

create table edit_log(
    id int references t1,
    editor_id int references users,
    edit_ts timestamp default current_timestamp );
```

with an update, wish to `update t1` and `insert into edit_lot`

```
update t1 set c1='abc', ... where id=456;
insert into edit_log( id, editor_id, current_timestamp );
```

this would be a pretty straightforward *except* for the arbitrary number of columns, eg,

```
update t1 set c1='abc', c2='def', editor_id=123 where id=456;
update t1 set c3='xyz', editor_id=123 where id=456;
```

how to write a rule for that?

Comment: Can be done with an ALSO rule, just try it. Don't forget that the PK of the log table will be {id,edit_ts}. The insert should *always* check for "NOT EXISTS" in the log table. Deletes are kind of special. And *always* check the resulting query plans.

Comment: right - the ALSO Rule rules (as it were).  but how to handle the arbitrary number of columns?

Comment: Since you log only the event (and not the data) the arbitrary columns do not matter. Either a record is hit by an update (insert,delete) or is is not. Maybe I don't understand what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

I think a [**trigger**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/triggers.html) will serve you better than a rule. Consider this demo.

#### Test setup

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE t1(id int, editor_id int, c1 text);
INSERT INTO t1(id, editor_id) VALUES (1,1),(2,2);
CREATE TEMP TABLE edit_log(id int, editor_id int, edit_ts timestamp);
```

#### Create trigger function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_t1_upaft_log()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN

IF OLD IS DISTINCT FROM NEW THEN -- to avoid empty updates
    INSERT INTO edit_log(id, editor_id, edit_ts)
    VALUES(NEW.id, NEW.editor_id, now()::timestamp);
END IF;

RETURN NULL; -- trigger will be fired AFTER updates, return value is irrelevant.

END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

#### Create trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER upaft_log
  AFTER UPDATE ON t1
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_t1_upaft_log();
```

#### Test

```
UPDATE t1 SET c1 = 'baz' WHERE id = 1;
SELECT * FROM edit_log; -- 1 new entry

UPDATE t1 SET c1 = 'baz' WHERE id = 1;
SELECT * FROM edit_log;  -- no new entry, update changed nothing!

UPDATE t1 SET c1 = 'blarg';
SELECT * FROM edit_log;  -- 2 new entries, update changed two rows.
```

#### Cleanup

```
DROP TRIGGER upaft_log ON t1;
DROP FUNCTION trg_t1_upaft_log()
-- Temp. tables will be dropped automatically at end of session.
```

#### Comment

It is very hard or plain impossible (depending on the details of your setup) for a rule to figure out which rows are updated.

A [trigger AFTER UPDATE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtrigger.html) can decide after the fact and is the better choice. Also easy to integrate with (most) additional triggers and / or rules in this scenario.

Comment: currently using trigger as you have outlined. but was trying to avoid the cheat by having `editor_id` as part of updated table.

Comment: @ccyoung: If `editor_id` can be derived from [`current_user`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-SESSION-TABLE) or `session_user`, you wouldn't need the extra column in the updated table. And a trigger isn't a cheat. It's the typical solution for the case.

Comment: as common with most web apps, all common users share the db user name. since pg connections are so expensive, this makes sense.  pg does not know the application user.  the cheat is having to maintain the `editor_id` column in the update table, not in using a trigger.  the idea behind using rules instead of triggers was an attempt to get around this cheat.